# Nominalizing particle combos

Tags: grammar, nominalization

I'm curious about the use of certain particles in combination with nominalizing particles こと and の。I know ことが、のは、etc are acceptable, but can one use particles such as と or など etc.? For instance, would the following sentence be grammatically correct or does it sound very strange?

> 喋ることと聞くことより読むことと書くことほうが上手だ。

Is there a better way to express this? Moreover, are ことと or ことなど or のと etc. acceptable particle combos?

Edit: I realize の should be used for experiential verbs, so maybe the following sentence is better:

> 喋るのと聞くのより読むのと書くのほうが上手だ。

Comment: The former one is fine, but the latter one "書くの方が得意だ" should be "書くことの方が得意だ". "書くのの方が得意だ" sounds strange.

Answer (score 3):

Your sentence is nearly perfect, but you need の between こと and ほう, because こと and ほう are both (special) nouns.

> 喋ることと聞くことより読むことと書くこと**の**ほうが上手だ。

(As an aside, you don't necessarily need nominalizers here. より and ほう can follow the dictionary-form of a verb, so you can say 喋ったり聞いたりするより読んだり書いたりする方が上手だ. [This question](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/29500/5010) is related.)

It's also possible to use nominalizer-の instead of こと, but it sounds less formal, and the combination of の-and-の (one for nominalization and one for linking) sounds odd to me.

> [△]喋るのと聞くのより読むのと書く**のの**ほうが上手だ。 (questionable)

ことなど is also an acceptable combination.

> 午前はメールを書くことなどに時間を使った。