# Does the legality/idiomaticness of verb+のの+方 depend on the verb?

Tags: grammar, nominalization, construction

Today when discussing language learning, I was corrected by a heritage Japanese speaker friend who changed what I said

> 多分書くのの方が難しいと思う

to

> 多分書くの<strike>の</strike>方が難しいと思う

However, the discussion [emerging from this post](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/29500) seems to suggest 書くのの方 is correct while 書くの方 is not. So I seem to have been in the right. But what about verb+のの+方?

[This site](http://people.uncw.edu/kanoy), maintained by [college level Japanese language teacher Kano Yoko](https://uncw.edu/languages/japanese/yokokano.html), claims:

> Q:日本語を話すのと書くのと、どちらの方が好きですか。Which one do you like, speaking or Writing Japanese?
> A:どちらも好きですが、**書くことの**（or **書くのの**）方がかんたんです。　I like both but writing is easier.
>
> (Note:のの in the 書くのの is often omitted especially in conversation.　Consider that it becomes a relative clause.)

In contrast, [this answer](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/62666/30454) suggests 書くののほうが上手だ sounds odd. So do the legality and idiomaticness of this construction depend on the verb? Do other verbs work better?

Side note: I did find some attestations of this: [書くのの方が問題。](https://ameblo.jp/nyoposachi/entry-11988062882.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

書く方が難しい or 書くことの方が難しい is the way to go.

書くの方が難しい is 100% ungrammatical. As I said in the linked question, 書くのの方が難しい is not 100% incorrect but it sounds fairly awkward at least to my ears. I suppose that heritage Japanese speaker felt the same way I did, but made a simple mistake while correcting it.

Comment: It was a [heritage speaker](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heritage_language) who grew up with one native speaking parent in an environment where nobody else around them spoke Japanese... namely ハーフ. I did double-check with them to make sure it wasn't a mistake on their part.

Comment: Hmm... 書くの方が難しい is somehow a very common mistake among Chinese natives speaking Japanese (it must be related to the Chinese grammar). Do you think it's related? And I didn't know the term heritage speaker, thanks for the info.

Comment: Well, it doesn't seem to be the case here. But since their dominant language isn't Japanese, there might be some issues in their use of the language.