# What does のの mean?

Tags: japanese-to-english

I'm reading おぼれかけた兄妹 by Areshima Takeo and I've come across the following phrase けれども二人がこっちに来るののおそいことおそいこと。Why this double のの?　And what about こと? A man is saving a girl's life in the sea and the two are approaching the shore very slowly because of the rough sea.

Comment: Related/dup https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/90471/45489

Answer (score 1):

The [こと](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/%E3%81%93%E3%81%A8/#jn-80375) is a particle, expressing exclamation in particular.

> 1 感動を表す。「まあ、きれいに咲いた―」「大変な人出だ―」

As for のの, your understanding is fine. 来るのの is equivalent to 来ることが.

Putting together, the part translates to *(their) coming is **so** slow!*.